# Manejo de comboBox con condicionales

Tags: java, combobox

Puedo manera las opciones que tengo en un comboBox desde una clase donde establezca operaciones o tengo que establecer necesariamnte las operaciones en la clase del Jframe?

```
    package controlador;

public class variables extends javax.swing.JFrame{

    private int metros;
    private double d0, d30, d60, d90, d120, d150, d180;
    private int temperatura, pavimento;
    private String hora;

    public variables() {
        this.metros = metros;
        this.d0 = d0;
    }

 
    public Double Consult() throws SQLException {
        Double area = null;
        if (Buscar()) {
            ResultSet res = null;
            conexion c = new conexion();

            int cont = 1;
            while (cont < 9) {
                String consult = ("select * from variables_p where id_variables = " + cont + "");
                res = c.consultar(consult);
                try {
                    while (res.next()) {
                        int metro = res.getInt("metros");
                        Double d0 = res.getDouble("D0");
                        Double d30 = res.getDouble("D30");
                        Double d60 = res.getDouble("D60");
                        Double d90 = res.getDouble("D90");

                        area = (6 * (d0 + (2 * d30) + (2 * d60) + d90)) / d0;
                        System.out.println("PRUEBA DE SUMA " + area + " ");
                        cont = cont + 3;
                        ResFomulas r = null ;/* Este llamdo se puede hacer?*/
                        String opcion = (String) r.jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
                        System.out.println(opcion);
//                        if (opcion.equals("TARATIMIENTP GRANULAR NO LIGADO")) {
//                            if (area < 0.10) {
//                                System.out.println("TARATIMIENTP GRANULAR NO LIGADO");
//                                System.out.println("DEBIL");
//                            } 
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    System.out.print("NO SE ESTABLECIO CONEXION CON LA BASE DE DATOS" + ex);
                }

            }

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "EL REGISTRO NO EXISTE");

        }

        return area;

    }


}
```

este codigo lo tengo en la clase de las formulas pero arroja error. Todo lo requiero realizar en esta clase llamanddo el ComboBox o lo que el usuario seleccione, no se si se pueda hacer o este realizando el llamado mal El Jframe lo llamo de la siguiente manera `ResFomulas r = null ;`

Comment: No has inicializado la variable ``r = null`` y la estas utilizando ``r.jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()``, puede ser ese el error

Comment: Sí esque eso es lo quiero hacer, dependiendo la seleccion que haga el usuario en el jFrame se escoga en la clase donde tengo las operaciones. ¿No lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Sí ResFormulas es el JFrame y tiene el ComoBox, significa que ResFormulas fue inicializado en algún lugar del programa (imagino en el main), esta es la variable que debes usar para r.jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();, algo relativamente fácil si usas el patrón MVC.

Comment: Si no pones el código completo deberías indicar cual es el error que te arroja para que sea más fácil de identificar.

Comment: desde ingreso esta linea de codigo  `String opcion = (String) r.jComboBox1.getSelectedItem(); `  Genera este `error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` y cuando genero los condicionales sgun lo que seleccione genera este error Excepción en el hilo `"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException Error`

Comment: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at controlador.variables.Consult(variables.java:140)
 at vista.ResFomulas.<init>(ResFomulas.java:26)
 at vista.seleccionArchivo.jButton2ActionPerformed(seleccionArchivo.java:135)
 at vista.seleccionArchivo.access$100(seleccionArchivo.java:21)
 at vista.seleccionArchivo$2.actionPerformed(seleccionArchivo.java:57)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
 at )`